# Resume download on DB exporting

Tags: sql-server, export

I am attempting to export a large database and import it to another PC over the Internet.

Sometimes my Internet connection fails resulting in a database export error, causing me to have to restart the export from the beginning.

Is it possible to resume the export from point where connection failed?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific.  How exactly are you doing this "export"?

Comment: Right click on database - tasks - export in SQL management studio

Comment: What exactly are your requirements? How often do you need to do this? Or is this a one-time operation?

Comment: Now it has to be done once, not sure whether I need to do this again. What I want to do is to copy database to another PC over Internet ( server is far away from me) with possibility to start download from the place where Internet connection was terminated.

Comment: There isn't a way to resume the process.

Answer (score 2):

If you have remote access to the server you are transfering I suggest you make a full back up of the database put it in a FTP or torrent (last option not very safe but easier if you don't know how to build a FTP server). Then when the file is transfered to the other server, you restore the backup.
This option will save you the trouble with the internet since the transfer to files will be local and FTP or torrent transfers can be paused/resumed if case of connection failed.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS does not resume export from point where the connection has failed.
Turque is right.

First, export (or backup) the database to your local machine, using SSMS.
Then, figure out how to transfer the file to another location. Check out Drop box, it might work for you and it's free.

Or once you create the export/backup file, split it into several smaller ones, so you know which one fails during the transfer. (I use Total Commander).
When you transfer all parts of the file, just combine them back into a single file and use it to restore the database